# Error en api-key javascript

Tags: javascript, axios, scraping, headers, fixedheader

Tengo un caso error de api-key, mi api-key tiene mayúsculas y minúsculas, en javascript no progresa mi ejecución, debido al error que muestra en api-key, por favor alguien sabe como resolver?

"x-api-key": "swGwRN7X65XLuBqFFsthpwxMjhXjxL9CrUmvtW70"

erro que muestra:
message: 'El mensaje de solicitud no se encuentra debidamente formateado.'

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: mi código es el siguiente: